# How to find out pid of the process from a signal is initiated in c++ in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, signals, fork, ipc

My application create child process using fork(). I have a signal handler in parent process. In signal handler i have to do different logic for parent and child.
ie in signal handler

```
case SIGSEGV:
              if (parent)
              {
                  cout<<"signal from parent";
              }
              else
              {
                  cout <<"signal from child";
              }
```

Is it possible? or i have to keep two different signal handlers?

Comment: Signals always go to the targeted process. SIGSEGV is always generated from within the process unless you are firing them at processes from outside (which isn't recommended in the case of `SIGSEGV`).

Comment: Not aware of any such "origin information" being available.

Answer (score 0):

Check the usage of `signalfd` ([man signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)) with `select` and `read` as this last will give you `signalfd_siginfo` structure, which has

```
uint32_t ssi_pid;     /* PID of sender */
```

Maybe this will help you.